# Why a PS script works in ISE but not in SQL Server 2012

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

Trying to copy a full backup from production server to reporting server and restore. I can get the script to run fine in PS ISE (64) but it gets verb errors when put into a SQL Agent job using the Powershell option.

```
$backuppath = "N:"
$destpath = "C:\Databases\Backup\AUREPORTING\Accumed\FULL" 
get-childitem -path $backuppath -Filter "AUEMRDATA_Accumed_FULL_*.bak" |
where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime |
select-object -last 1 |
copy-item -Destination (join-path $destpath "AUEMRDATA_Accumed_FULL.BAK")
```

For some reason it does not like the pipe `|` command to filter. The error information returned by PowerShell is:

> 'Invalid Path: 'C:\Databases\Backup\AUREPORTING\Accumed\FULL\AUEMRDATA_Accumed_FULL.BAK'.

Job is run by account with sysadmin rights on both servers

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools.  Perhaps this is better question for serverfault.com?

Answer (score 4):

It could be that the current location in the SQL Job step is set to the SQL provider.  Try prepending the path with "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::" to point it to the right place.

Comment: Hey Mike - good call. I was testing from my desktop using SSMS to run the agent but when I switched to run the test from SSMS on the server then the powershell script worked. I now just have to put in a delay to give the job time to copy the file before going to the next step and having the restore start since it cannot find the file until it is done copying it.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.  I was running a powershell script locally and everything worked fine.  However I kept getting the 'Invalid Path' error whenever running it from SQL Agent.  I prepended the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::" to my path and it worked.  

So for instance it ended up being "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\my-server\file.txt".

Comment: Tank you, this helped me!!